# form submit not working correct with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have ajax validation function and when ajax validation is true then i use:

```
$("#test_form").submit();
```

it is work fine but any time i can click Enter and submit a form when form is not validated (skip validation process and pass wrong data).
 i try put

```
$("#test_form").submit(function(){event.preventDefault();});
```

then still can submit with enter when data is wrong 
or

```
$("#sample_form").submit(function(){false});
```

then i cant submit any time.

How to submit only when ajax is true?

Comment: Use `$("#test_form").submit(function(event){event.preventDefault();});` notice `function(event)`

Comment: @Satpal Why didn't you write it as an answer?..

Comment: @Satpal its not working when ajax true: $("#test_form").submit();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your answer is said in the comment section :

---

> Use `$("#test_form").submit(function(event){event.preventDefault();});` notice `function(event)`

*– Satpal*

---

Then you'll notice an other problem, your form will never submit after the AJAX call. That is because you use `$("#test_form").submit();` to submit, which is the jQuery triggering the event. When jQuery trigger the event, it will always be prevented by the `preventDefault`.

What you need to do is to use the native JavaScript event :

```
$("#test_form")[0].submit();
```

When you are using the native handler, the event you have been added with jQuery will not trigger. It will instead directly send the form.

Answer (score 0):

In Submit button, Use `onclick with return` then On press enter it will check first javascript validation.

Comment: i dont have submit button i wanna submit form when ajax validation return true then $("#test_form").submit();

Comment: For god sake don't suggest inline event hanlder

Comment: success: function validate(data) {
            if (data == 1) {
                
               $("#test_form").submit();
             
}